Counting Measures in DAX in Power BI
I have a visualization in Power BI that reflects the category of a customer based on their market share. The market share is a DAX Measure which changes dynamically based on the selections in slicers (products, timeframes etc). The Category is a DAX Measure based on the market share. This means that the category changes depending on the slicer selections. This image shows the visualization output:

Both the market share and the category are measures, and do not appear in a table.
I want to count how many customers appear in each category.  How do I count the categories?
I've tried using calculated tables using SUMMARIZE and SELECTEDVALUE (unsuccessful) as these do not change the values in the calculated table based on Slicer selections.
This seems so simple, but I've been hunting for weeks and not making progress. Any advice appreciated greatly!

Can you share your model? and the DAX code of the measures already created?

Thanks Amira, here is the link to the model in Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RNDze31Lb_4nTAGKZMKKNjYk6fywIrt5/view?usp=sharing

Ok perfect now can you provide an example of input and expected output based on your data ?

Hi Amira,
The input will be based on the slicer selections.
The output should look like the following example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RawtLDbXLXSwi079eQEq4Iq4AaQzU4qr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103002249299447633792&rtpof=true&sd=true
I hope this helps.

This is the calculation you should use, which is based on: https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/:
CountCategory = 
VAR CustomersInCategory =
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( SalesTable[customer] ),
        VAR MarketShare = [MarketShare]
        VAR CategoryForCustomer =
            FILTER (
                CategoryTable,
                NOT ISBLANK ( MarketShare )
                    && MarketShare > CategoryTable[MinRange]
                    && MarketShare <= CategoryTable[MaxRange]
            )
        VAR IsCustomerInCategory =
            NOT ISEMPTY ( CategoryForCustomer )
        RETURN
            IsCustomerInCategory
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( SalesTable[customer] ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( CustomersInCategory )
    )
RETURN
    Result

The output looks like this:


Thanks Mark, you're a lifesaver! And thanks for the learning link to dynamic segmentation.
Craig

@PointyScrute no problem!  Please don't forget to accept this answer
